# Best way to solve these sparse symmetric positive definite almost-banded problems?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, sparse-matrices

I am trying to find an efficient way to solve linear systems for the case of sparse symmetric positive definite matrices which have a banded structure except for the case of a few "outliers" that are outside the band.  The matrix sizes i'm dealing with are about 2000x2000 or less in size.  They are square.

Sometimes, the matrices have relatively small bandwidth (for instance, bandwidth of 9) and have a structure that looks like this:

[Small bandwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYfjJ.png)

My understanding is that when the matrix looks like this, the most efficient way to solve this is to use a banded Gaussian elimination.  Is this correct?

Other times, though, the bandwidth of the matrix looks much worse, but only do to a few outliers, like this:

[Large Bandwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NbdQ.png)

Notice that the matrix is still very banded, except for the few outliers which cause the bandwidth to be much larger.  I have tried using bandwidth-reducing reordering algorithms like Symmetric reverse Cuthill-McKee, but those only slightly reduce the bandwidth.  Is there a better way to solve these cases efficiently?

Comment: Re your first comment, have you ever tried Krylov subspace methods? in practice they can be yet faster at a very slight accuracy tradeoff which typically does not matter for sensible applications. Re your second question, a wild shot: could you maybe write the matrix as $A=B+S$ were $B$ is the banded matrix and $S$ a very sparse matrix, then solve for $B$ which may (?) give you a solution that's fairly close to the true solution. Using that as a starting point you could then use an iterative method to further diminish the residual?

Comment: I also should have mentioned that my right-hand side contains many columns (as low as 10, as many as thousands).  This would be an argument against using a Krylov solver, right?